# Git: Allow amending commits without erasing the history

Tags: git, git-amend, fast-forward

Is there an option in Git to allow amending commits in a central repository (e.g. to change the description, committer name or his/her e-mail address), but not allowing to erase the entire history.

As I understand it, by default both are allowed ([`receive.denynonfastforwards = false`](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)).

Answer (score 2):

There is fundamentally no way for git to tell the difference between such changes to commits.

You *can*, as a human, check that the commits have the same tree (i.e. `git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}`), and I am vaguely aware of `git-notes` but have never used it.